# Python script run from a batch file on MAC

Tags: python, batch-file

I have a script in python that uses the Numpy+MKL.

I have a recently bought a MAC and have been transferring to it all my work from an old Windows machine. Note that I have created a Windows partition on my MAC where to transfer everything I had on my windows machine

On both MAC and old Win machine, if I open the py script with "Edit with IDLE===>F5" the script runs just fine

On the Win machine I had a bat file that was calling the py script. The code for the bat file is below

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO.
"C:\PYTHONCODE\Script1.py"
ECHO.
CLS
EXIT
```

The problem with MAC is that the code crashes when called via a batch file and seems related to MKL and MAC.

Is there a way to make the script running via batch in the Win partition of the MAC as I was doing with the old machine? Would I need to install any other package on my MAC I am not aware of?

Comment: When you haven't booted with the Windows Operating System, all you will be doing is trying to run a script from another drive partition, probably with an NT File System. So what you appear to be telling us/me, is that usually a Windows Batch File, _(extension `.bat`, or `.cmd`)_ runs without issue, in a MacOS terminal, but on this occasion it does not. So please provide us with a working Windows Batch script, so that we can reproduce that, and please explain to us where `C:\PYTHONCODE` is, _(is `C:` assigned to the drive containing your Windows Operating System? )_.

Comment: Also, please explain why you need a Windows batch file to run a `.py` file in MacOS. Your MAC should already have `python`, so it would make more sense to run a `.py` file as an argument to the MacOS `python`, and, if necessary, from a shell script, not a Windows batch file. Usually `C:` would be an assigned drive letter on Windows, but on MacOS, drives are mounted to locations within the root heirarchy, so I'm not sure how you expect `C:` to have any meaning in MacOS.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, I have found and worked out a solution. Windows batch works perfectly on the Win partition in MAC. Thanks again and have a good day

Comment: Why not post that solution as an answer then for others to learn from? After all, this site works both ways, it isn't just for your benefit, it's for everyone!

Comment: The truth? I'd really like to post an answer as a solution to my question. But looks like you are now really interested on it while you forgot your original comment to my question that has now been deleted. Recall that and then you might understand why it is not my intention to let you know the solution: indeed, this site works both ways, the both ways is related to your original answer. Life is more than about coding, hence I suggest you to to reply in a polite way to start with: gold and platinum badges doesn't help on that

Comment: I do have a solution and I really do regards StackOverflow readership worthy indeed. It is not I do not want other people to know: as said, recall your original comment, especially if you talk in behalf of StackOverflow. Post it again, that will explain why

Comment: Looks like someone had a solution, the same I’ve applied and you were looking for. Enjoy the solution @Compo. Hope this helps everyone learning process. Clearly it did not need details or clarity. Sometimes is enough knowing the answer and that a MAC has a partition to run Win ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have an intel processor on your MAC. I also assume you used the "strong" way to set your bootcamp C partition to run Windows 10 OS

My assumption, please correct me if I am wrong, are based on the fact that all other batch jobs are running fine from task scheduler despite you use a MAC and you have created a partition to run Win10 OS

This is an issue that can be caused by one of the following:

1. either you pip installation of numpy+mkl missed to install part of the whl. In this case then you should pip unistall your numpy and then pip install again making sure you have not an error.

though from the description of your issue I think solution 1) it is not what you are after but your problem is caused by something else, hence before trying solution 1) please try this

2. force your python code to run on bootcamp C by properly setting it on task scheduler via the batch job

I believe what you are facing is due to the fact that despite there is a partition you have a single hard drive and this will be like having two tv and a single remote control...despite you want to change channel on one tv, if both are on you'll end up changing channel on both

Let me know how it goes

Comment: Hi and tanks for your reply. This is exactly what I did and all works fine.